# smoothing outer edges in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, smoothing, contourf

have two questions maybe someone can help me.
I want to plot a stereographic projection with contoruf and want to  color the higher parts in the Z direction in Matplotlib.
For that i have two questions.

1. I’m plotting with contourf before im using meshgrid and griddata, the the other edges are not smooth how can i smooth them?
   [image]i
2. I want to have a log scale in Z how can i do that, i tried to use ticker.LogLocator but then i got just some parts colored.

Here my code:

```
# craation of a 2D grid
xi = np.linspace(min(X), max(X))
yi = np.linspace(min(Y), max(Y))

X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

##### interpolation
Z1 = griddata(X, Y, Z,xi,yi)

plt.contourf(X1,Y1,Z1,50,cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,vmax=abs(Z1).max(),
             locator=ticker.LogLocator)

plt.colorbar()

plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)

plt.show()
plt.set_zscale('log')
plt.set_xlabel('X')
plt.set_ylabel('Y')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the first question:

You can smooth the contour values doing:

```
zmin = Z1.min()
zmax=Z1.max()
levels=linspace(zmin, zmax, 400)
```

and then pass `levels` as an argument to `plt.contourf()`.

To smooth the outer edges you have to use more values in your 2-D grid, which can be achieved passing the number of values you want when using `linspace()`:

```
nx = 1000
ny = 1000
xi = np.linspace(min(X), max(X), nx)
yi = np.linspace(min(Y), max(Y), ny)
```

Comment: thanks it helps to smooth the graph, but i also want to smooth the boundary edges of the Graph want i can to here?